# Within a Random Forest, is there a way to detect which trees are more correlated with each other?

Tags: correlation, random-forest, redundancy-analysis

One common piece of advice given when you train a Random Forest model (RF) is, increasing the number of trees as much as possible, until the accuracy doesn't improves anymore.

But, is *quantity* always better than *quality*?

Given that ***not all the randomly-grown estimators are equally correlated with each other,*** what if we could remove some of them —the less relevant ones?

What if we could linearly compare among the many trees, and remove those ones that are similar to each other, ie. that are ***redundant*** and don't provide an *information gain* to the model?

Additionally, if we could not remove them, could there be a way to assign weights to each of them? Instead of letting all the estimators having the same importance, which seems a mistake to me.

I haven't seen anything related on this topic, that's why I ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what if we could remove some of them — the less relevant ones?

The keyword you're looking for here is "ensemble pruning" (not to be confused with pruning nodes off an individual tree). See for example [adnan_OptimizingNumberTrees_201](https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0950705116302301)6` and the references in the introduction.

> could there be a way to assign weights to each of them?

Check out [bernard_DynamicRandomForests_2012](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167865512001274) and the follow-up [xu_ImplementationPerformanceOptimization_2017](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8250371). See also [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160571/a-question-about-dynamic-random-forest/160892#160892) on Dynamic Random Forests including some clarifications by the author. [Complement Random Forest](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Complement-Random-Forest-Adnan-Islam/9df325950d5a560ce71026a68bcf1a32cd4caa2a) might also be interesting.

(I'd appreciate if you shared any other findings you make, I'm looking into this topic myself currently).

I also pasted some personal notes with references [here](https://hackmd.io/@6gkvtUwiTPyWK4EgAnJMVw/Bk4IBY1hh).

Answer (score 1):

People have suggested using lasso regression to select trees from a random forest (eg [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00949655.2020.1814776))

An alternative would be to just use boosted trees. Boosting isn't quite the same because each tree is grown to contain new information -- this also means that boosting is harder to parallelise.